# How to check the lex input as a single input

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

i have make a lex file as it shown below:

```
%%
[\t\n]
"if" {printf("IF_TOKEN\n");}
"else" {printf("ELSE_TOKEN\n");}
"while" {printf("WHILE_TOKEN\n");}
"FOR" {printf("FOR_TOKEN\n");}
"BREAK" {printf("BREAK_TOKEN\n");}
"float" {printf("FLOAT_TOKEN\n");}
"int" {printf("INT_TOKEN\n");}
"long" {printf("LONG_TOKEN\n");}
"return" {printf("RETURN_TOKEN\n");}
"defFunction" {printf("DEFFUNCTION_TOKEN\n");}
"defClass" {printf("DEFCLASS_TOKEN\n");}
"\(" {printf("PAROPEN_TOKEN\n");}
"\)" {printf("PARCLOS_TOKEN\n");}
"\{" {printf("CBROPEN_TOKEN\n");}
"\}" {printf("CBRCLOS_TOKEN\n");}
"<" {printf("LESSTHN_TOKEN\n");}
">" {printf("GRTRTHN_TOKEN\n");}
"=" {printf("EQUALTO_TOKEN\n");}
"!=" {printf("NEQUALTO_TOKEN\n");}
"\+" {printf("SUM_TOKEN\n");}
"-" {printf("MINUS_TOKEN\n");}
"\*" {printf("STAR_TOKEN\n");}
"\/" {printf("SLASH_TOKEN\n");}
"%" {printf("REMAIN_TOKEN\n");}
"\[" {printf("BRAOPEN_TOKEN\n");}
"\]" {printf("BRACLOS_TOKEN\n");}
";" {printf("SEMICOL_TOKEN\n");}
[-]?[1-9][0-9]* {printf("NUMBER\n");}
[A-Za-z&_$][A-Za-z$_]* {printf("ID\n");}
. {printf("ERROR");}

%%
int yywrap (void) {
return 1;
}
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
   yylex();
   return 0;
}
```

if i give 125apple as an input to this lex file after compile the .l file, it should print error but it print 
    NUMBER
    ID
how can i give 125apple as a single input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many languages, that's exactly how `125apple` would be lexed, in part because that's the way a naive lex scanner definition works.

If you want it to be an error, you need to explicitly make it an error, by adding a pattern which will match erroneous tokens. By putting it after the pattern which matches valid numbers, you avoid triggering an error on inputs which match both patterns, so the error pattern can also match valid tokens. That makes it a bit easier to write.

```
0|[-]?[1-9][0-9]* {printf("NUMBER\n");}
[-]?[0-9]+[0-9A-Za-z_]* {printf("ERROR\n");}
[A-Za-z&_$][A-Za-z$_]* {printf("ID\n");}
```

---

Above, I made a little change: your number pattern does not recognize 0, so I added it.

The error line not only catches `125apple`. It also catches other erroneous tokens, like `0037` and `-0`. (I'm not convinced that `-0` should be an error; you might want to fix that.) It does not treat `123$apple` as an error, so you might want to change that, too.

Comment: it should be an error because i want to my variable couldnt be started with numbers.also when i give emad/ as input, it gives me ID SLASH_TOKEN and for all formats.i dont think that it should necessary to write ERROR pattern for all these formats,should i?if i could say the lex that each input without space is a single input,it should work correctly

Comment: @EmadSmart: Your choice. "Because I want it to be" is a perfectly valid explanation. Just remember it the next time you ask yourself why some language you're using works the way it does :)

Comment: it is just for my learning it is not a real language and also 125e cannot be a valid variable name C++ , can it?

Comment: @EmadSmart: In C++, it's a valid preprocessing number token, but it cannot be translated to a number so it will eventually cause an error. In python, though, 125apple is two tokens (a number followed by a variable) and in C++11 users can define their own number suffixes, so it may be that in some environment 125apple is a valid number. Of course, 125e is not valid: floating point numbers need exponents, so 125e7 would be fine.